# Share user login between wordpress instalations

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I'm using the following aproache to share user login details between wordpress installations.
The issue is that admins, on the secondary installation, have no rights to access the dashboard.

Any ideas why?

Primary database “MyMainWPDB” (leaving it untouched)

Secondary database “MySecondaryWPDB”

```
drop wp_users

drop wp_usermeta

CREATE VIEW wp_users AS SELECT * FROM MyMainWPDB.wp_users

CREATE VIEW wp_usermeta AS SELECT * FROM MyMainWPDB.wp_usermeta
```

use the following wp-config.php info on both instances

```
define(‘AUTH_KEY’, ‘xxx’);

define(‘SECURE_AUTH_KEY’, ‘xxx’);

define(‘LOGGED_IN_KEY’, ‘xxx’);

define(‘NONCE_KEY’, ‘xxx’);

define(‘AUTH_SALT’, ‘xxx’);

define(‘SECURE_AUTH_SALT’, ‘xxx’);

define(‘LOGGED_IN_SALT’, ‘xxx’);

define(‘NONCE_SALT’, ‘xxx’);
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

wp_user_roles on MySecondaryWPDB only had the translation role for some reason.
Copied data from MyMainWPDB and issue was no longuer there.

One thing on this approach is that if you add user roles on any of the installations, they will not update to the other since new roles are writen on the wp_options table.

Anyways, fits my needs :)

Comment: Where do you add this code?

Comment: I need something similar
I am currently sharing the user roles and capabilities using the KINSTA Blog approach. But how do i share the same plugin database table?

FOR INSTANCE Table wp_user_history in siteA with wp2_user_history in siteB?